# Current Coordinate of bufferedImage Object in java

Tags: java

Is there anyway to find the current position of a buffered image on jpanel?

I draw an image on buffer, named it currentImage. Now I want to move it around a Panel by using affine transform.

To do translation by using mouse, I have to know the current position, new position and update the new position.

But I have trouble in getting the current position of the BufferedImage. There is no method in the IDE's suggestion working.

Can anyone give me an idea how to do this ?? Thanks!

**EDIT**

this is my draw and paintComponent method:

```
private void draw(){
        AlphaComposite ac = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC);
        int w = this.getWidth();    int h = this.getHeight();

        if (currentImage == null || width != w || height != h){
            width = w;
            height = h;

            currentImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

            graphics = currentImage.createGraphics();
            graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_GASP);
            drawClearAndGradedArea(graphics);
            drawActualRunway(graphics, width, height, width, height);
            drawLeftToRight(graphics);
            drawRightToLeft(graphics);
            drawCentralLine(graphics);
            graphics.setComposite(ac);
        }
    }
```

paintComponent()

```
@Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.clearRect(0,0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHints(rh);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_GASP);
        /*
         * main components on panel
         */

        this.draw();
        this.animation();

        g2d.drawImage(currentImage, transform, this);

        drawNote(g2d);
        g2d.dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Depends on how you draw the image. Is it an imageicon? Are you drawing by overriding paintcomponent? Some code would help us help you :)

Comment: The image is not an icon :) It actually a graph I draw by hand. And yes, I draw it by overriding paintComponent. I would edit a part of my code so you will easily see how it actually drawn on panel

Comment: As far as I can see, the current position of the image only depends on the `transform` that is used for painting. If I understood this correctly, you should be able to obtain the current image position with `Point2D p = transform(new Point(0,0), null);`, but some more information about how `transform` is computed might be helpful to give a more focussed answer.

Comment: Nevermind, I solved the problem! The image is now moving around my panel perfectly! Thank you anyway!!